# Vaadin binding setBean to DAO still null

Tags: java, spring, vaadin

How to bind data from TextFields to DAO object? this doesnt works still  null Entity of DAO, all binding is set OK

```
public void savePersonToDB() {
  personDAO = new PersonDAO();  
  binder.setBean(personDAO);    
    if (binder.validate().isOk()) {
    repository.save(personDAO);
```

Answer (score 0):

> personDAO = new PersonDAO();

The `personDAO` instantiated with default constructor.

> binder.setBean(personDAO);

This means loads the values from the `personDAO` instance. Sets PersonDAO to be updated when any bound field is updated.

To set the form properties to `PersonDAO` bean, you can use `FieldGroup` which makes it easier to bind fields to a bean. You can read more, how [data binding](https://vaadin.com/docs/v7/framework/datamodel/datamodel-itembinding.html) works from Vaadin Doc.

For example;

```
// Have an item
PropertysetItem item = new PropertysetItem();
item.addItemProperty("name", new ObjectProperty<String>("Zaphod"));
item.addItemProperty("age", new ObjectProperty<Integer>(42));

// Define a form as a class that extends some layout
class MyForm extends FormLayout {
// Member that will bind to the "name" property
TextField name = new TextField("Name");

// Member that will bind to the "age" property 
@PropertyId("age")
TextField ageField = new TextField("Age");

public MyForm(Item item) {
    // Add the fields
    addComponent(name);
    addComponent(ageField);

    // Now bind the member fields to the item
    FieldGroup binder = new FieldGroup(item);
    binder.bindMemberFields(this);
}
}

// Create one
MyForm form = new MyForm(item);

// And the form can be used in an higher-level layout
layout.addComponent(form);
```

The [new data binding API](https://vaadin.com/download/release/8.0/8.0.0/release-notes.html) replaces the old Container, Item, Property, FieldGroup, Validator, Converter and related classes with new mechanisms. Also components using those are replaced with updated implementations using the new API, and the old data binding API and components have been moved to separate compatibility packages for ease of migration.

Here is an interesting blog from Vaadin, would help you to understand how `Binder` works in Vaadin 8.
[How to bind your form to your domain model – the Vaadin 8 style](https://vaadin.com/blog/vaadin-8-binder)

Comment: I understand but when I open form, I write form data and want map it to fields in java DAO ...... how to fill from fields form to personDAO and bind to this object? readBean and writeBean doesnt work too, or I have to handly set fields to dao like dao.setValue1(field.getValue1) and binding is useless for ordinary fill when I want fill empty personDAO?  I thought vaadin has some clever mechanism for this

Comment: @petmik I have updated the answer, hoping it would help you to resolve your problem.

Comment: what packages are FieldGroup, PropertysetItem ? i didnt find those classes in java

Comment: These are part of Vaadin Framework https://vaadin.com/api/7.7.5/com/vaadin/data/fieldgroup/FieldGroup.html https://vaadin.com/api/7.7.3/com/vaadin/data/util/PropertysetItem.html

Comment: ooops I have 8.3 version

Comment: The new data binding API replaces the old Container, Item, Property, `FieldGroup`, Validator, Converter and related classes with new mechanisms. I will update the answer!